# Django. How to make loop for bootstrap collapse

Tags: python, django, django-models, bootstrap-4

Can you help with better way to process many similar bootstrap collapse for page ?

I have 12 similar collapse, where collapse title it is a verbose name of model field, and collapse text it is a model field value.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-10 mx-auto mb-3">
  <div class="accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="card border-top border-bottom-0 border-left border-right border-light">
      <div class="card-header border-bottom border-light" role="tab" id="heading" style="background-color:#DDDFDF;">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse">
          <h5 class="black-text font-weight-normal mb-0">
            Title of collapse where i want get verbose_name of model
          </h5>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading" data-parent="#accordionEx">
        <div class="card-body">
          Some text where i want get value of model field
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i make loop for this model and substitute name and value from model field instead creat 12 similar block of code ?

Answer (score 0):

U can use builtin django template tags like this

```
{% for field in model %}
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-10 mx-auto mb-3">
  <div class="accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="card border-top border-bottom-0 border-left border-right border-light">
      <div class="card-header border-bottom border-light" role="tab" id="heading" style="background-color:#DDDFDF;">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse">
          <h5 class="black-text font-weight-normal mb-0">
            {{ field.name }}
          </h5>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading" data-parent="#accordionEx">
        <div class="card-body">
          {{ field.text }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Note: make sure u properly indent that I have just copied yr answer.

Also you have to pass context to your template from your views.py file of app in order to loop through it.

you can read more about django builtin tags [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/)

Comment: This is not what i want)

For example i have a model of a product and i want to do loop for fields and display each field name and text, but don't specify them manually

Comment: so, let's say u have a model of products containing fields like name, description, price. then you can make a dictionary in your views.py file like context= { 'product' : product=product.object.all() } and pass it to the template like return render(request, 'template_name', context=context) then inside the template you will be able to access all the fields of your products model like {{ products.name }} then just put it anywhere you want in loop as shown above.

Comment: So, in the template for each field I need to specify 
{{ products.name }},
{{ products.descriptions }}, {{ products.price }}

for each field in model to display?

Comment: yes suppose you have 3 products in your db then there will be three Bootstrap collapse, one for each product

Comment: I know how to use the django builtin tags. This is exactly what I want to avoid. How to loop through the names and data in the model instead, and output them to collapse so as not to duplicate them